# Jenkins multibranch plugin and RVM

Tags: ruby, jenkins, rvm

I'm trying to use RVM with the jenkins multibranch plugin. I keep running into a problem with RVM not being found. I'm thinking it's probably due to the fact the jenkins user doesn't have a true shell.

I installed RVM by using `sudo su -s /bin/bash jenkins` then following the RVM installation instructions.

My Jenkins file uses:

```
sh 'source ~/.bashrc'
sh 'rvm use 2.2.1@my-project'
```

The bashrc file looks like:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

When I commit a change and the build runs, I get this error:

```
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Chalk Web/develop@tmp/durable-27a33a52/script.sh: line 2: rvm: command not found
```

If I ssh to the machine, and run the `sudo su -s /bin/bash jenkins` command I can run RVM fine. However, I assume that jenkins doesn't have a login shell when it's running the build. How can I allow Jenkins to see RVM?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a way to make sure all your shell commands are executed with a login shell, and this solved my issue:

```
sh '''#!/bin/bash -l
rvm use 2.2.1@my-project
bundle install
etc...
'''
```